# Manipulating Values in Pandas DataFrames

Tags: python, pandas, string, dataframe

I am trying to create and apply a function `def change(x):` which modifies a single column of values `grocery` in the grocery data frame as shown in the image below
[grocery data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPlLj.png)

I want to achieve the result in the image below
[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/blUOH.png)

I am at the beginner level in python but I know I can use the `map()` or `apply()` functions to solve this. My main problem is using the `split()` method to achieve the result as the values in the `category` column are of varying lengths. Or are there other string manipulation methods that can be used?

```html
import pandas as pd

groceries = {
'grocery':['Tesco's wafers', 'Asda's shortbread', 'Aldi's lemon tea', 'Sainsbury's croissant', 'Morrison's doughnut', 'Amazon fresh's peppermint tea', 'Bar becan's pizza', 'Pound savers' shower gel'],
'category':['biscuit', 'biscuit', 'tea', 'bakery', 'bakery', 'tea', 'bakery', 'hygiene'],
'price':[0.99, 1.24, 1.89, 0.75, 0.50, 2.5, 4.99, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(groceries)
df

# function to modify a single column of values - grocery
def change(x):
    return df['grocery].str.split(' ').str[1]

df = pd.DataFrame(groceries)

df['grocery'] = df['grocery'].map(change)
df


# Expected DataFrame
groceries = pd.DataFrame({
'grocery':['Wafers', 'Shortbread', 'Lemon Tea', 'Croissant', 'Doughnut', 'Peppermint Tea', 'Pizza', 'Shower Gel'],
'category':['biscuit', 'biscuit', 'tea', 'bakery', 'bakery', 'tea', 'bakery', 'hygiene'],
'price':[0.99, 1.24, 1.89, 0.75, 0.50, 2.5, 4.99, 2]
})
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please post the input and expected dataframes as code in your question. Don't post them as images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope this works for your solution, I split it with "'" comma and then start it with from 1 index of a string. It depends on conditions

```
import pandas as pd

groceries = {
    'grocery': [
        "Tesco's wafers", "Asda's shortbread", "Aldi's lemon tea",
        "Sainsbury's croissant", "Morrison's doughnut",
        "Amazon fresh's peppermint tea", "Bar becan's pizza",
        "Pound savers' shower gel"
    ],
    'category': [
        'biscuit', 'biscuit', 'tea', 'bakery', 'bakery', 'tea', 'bakery',
        'hygiene'
    ],
    'price': [0.99, 1.24, 1.89, 0.75, 0.50, 2.5, 4.99, 2]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(groceries)
# split it with "'" comma and then start it with from 1 index of a string 
# if multiple conditions for grocery string then 

# def grocery_chng(x):
#     # specify multiple conditions to replace a string
#     return x
# df['grocery'] = df['grocery'].apply(grocery_chng)

df['grocery'] = df['grocery'].apply(lambda x: x.split("'")[1][1:].title())
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a dataframe df with your original data:

```
df['grocery'] = df['grocery'].apply(lambda x: (x.split("'s", 1) if "'s" in x else x.split("'", 1))[1].title())
```